# error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'

Tags: c++, function, parameters, c2664

having some trouble passing a function as a parameter of another function...

> ERROR: Error  1   error C2664: 'wrapper'
>   : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'int' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'

```
int inc( int n )
{
    return n + 1 ;
}

int dec( int n )
{
    return n - 1 ;
}

int wrapper(   int i, int func(int)   )
{
    return func( i ) ;
}   


int main(){

    int a = 0 ;

    a = wrapper(  3, inc( 3 )  ) ;

    return 0 ;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the result of a function call `inc(3)` to `wrapper`, NOT a function pointer as it expects.

`a = wrapper(3, &inc) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Your call is passing an integer, the return value from calling `inc(3)`, i.e. 4.

That is not a function pointer.

Perhaps you meant:

```
a = wrapper(3, inc);
```

This would work, and assign a to the value of calling `int` with the parameter `3`.

Answer (score 1):

As it is now, `wrapper` takes an `int` and a pointer to a function that takes one `int` and returns an `int`. You are trying to pass it an int and an int, because instead of passing the *a pointer to the function*, you're *calling* the function and passing the return value (an `int`). To get your code to work as (I think) you expect, change your call to `wrapper` to this:

```
a = wrapper(3, &inc);
```

Comment: many thanks for the quick replies everyone ..I had this problem once before and somehow managed to get it working without understanding the issue ...now this time it works and I understand why ..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 a = wrapper(  3, inc( 3 )  ) ;
```

is effectively:

```
a = wrapper(3, 4);
```

I think you mean:

```
a = wrapper(3, inc);
```

This passes a pointer to the inc() function as the second argument to wrapper().

Answer (score 1):

i had this error in my program:

```
error C2664: 'glutSpecialFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,int)'
```

because i had wrote the method definition later than main method.
when i cut the main method and paste it later than definition of function, the error removed.